# Port Forwarding, Render Console Warning — Rails v4.2.6

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, socket

Forwarded port on local router *192.168.1.4:3000* to allow public access w/ my IP address.
When viewing my rails app @ http://47.145.229.103:3000/ everything displays correctly, but theres a console render warning from any access point other than localhost:3000.
**When Viewed via localhost:3000**

```
WayyLoww:~/Development/Rails/Syn$ bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-10-11 00:38:31] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-10-11 00:38:31] INFO  ruby 2.3.1 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-darwin16]
[2016-10-11 00:38:31] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5932 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-11 00:38:34 -0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by VisitorsController#index as HTML
  Rendered visitors/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_nav_links_for_auth.html.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (7.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 243ms (Views: 234.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**When viewed via IP address**

```
Started GET "/" for 47.145.229.103 at 2016-10-11 00:41:32 -0700
Cannot render console from 47.145.229.103! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by VisitorsController#index as HTML
  Rendered visitors/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_nav_links_for_auth.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (4.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 75ms (Views: 74.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

If everything is loading properly, why is this render console error occurring, and what would need to be done to correct this?